# Is there a way to set the ionic popover parent's element?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, popover

I'd like to know if there is a way to change the ionic popover to reside into the app-root rather than directly into the body?

The reason being that it is impossible for me to show a kendo dialog in front of a ionic popover because of the stacking context.